# How copy List<Entity> to new List without ID?

Tags: java, hibernate, list

I have some Entity for example `User`

```
class User{
 private Long id;
 private String Name;
 private List<Role> roles;
}
```

When I get this User from DB I have `user = UserDao.getUser(1);`

And I have some `List<Role> someList;`

I need copy `user.getRoles()` to `someList`

But if I write `user = user.getRoles()` all `Role` objects in `someList` have ID not null;

I want to set `someList` to another User but if ID  is not null, I can not use it.

I can make this

```
for (Role role: user.getRoles()) {
            role.setId(null);
            someList.add(role);
        }
```

But I think it is bad practice. Maybe you know best way?

Comment: Can you provide us more complete code to understand what you are aiming for? I do not quite understand.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are inside a transaction and that don't want to reuse the `Role` objects across different users: With the way hibernate works, you'll need create *new* role objects, otherwise Hibernate will know that you assigned the same instance to another object, and will completely ignore that you have set the id to null.

Personally, I think would create a static method in `Role` class called `clone` that receives a list of roles and instantiates new ones (without an id).

<del>The big, important question is: Do you really want to not re-use the role objects? And potentially have 2 roles with the same data, but just assigned to different users (that might go against 3rd normal form... but this depends on your requirements).</del>

Comment: actually my problem is a little different. The user is just an example. When you open the editing form, even if something has changed, I need to create a copy of the object and assign it a new version. save the old object, too. ie do not update the object and copy it. but this property contains the two  lists with other objects

Comment: Can you shared some example that you have advised?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example. I made up the Role Class myself since you did not provide any source code of it:

```
public class Role {
    private int id;
    private String someAttribute;
    private int otherAttribute;

    public Role(String someAttribute, int otherAttribute) {
        this.someAttribute = someAttribute;
        this.otherAttribute = otherAttribute;
    }

    // Other class methods omited for readability

    public Role clone() {
        return new Role(someAttribute, otherAttribute);
    }

}
```

Edit: And you could do your for loop like this:

```
for (Role role: user.getRoles()) {
    someList.add(role.clone());
}
```